# Is there an offline postgres proxy tool/library?

Tags: postgresql, proxy, offline

I'm looking for a tool something like PL/Proxy, but that will work when the database is offline by queuing queries for later execution..  It is only needed for some very simple inserts and updates (and can be easily handled by a stored procedure call), so naturally the client app doesn't need to know the response in real time.

Transient failures (like DB is offline) ought to be retried, and permanent failures ought to be logged.

The client app is written in perl, but a true proxy server shouldn't care about that.

I'm prepared to write my own, but if someone has already invented this wheel, I'd love to save some time.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if one of the off-the-shelf connection poolers could be configured to do what you want.  You might want to look at pgpool, pgbouncer, and Apache's DBCP.

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on your needs.  You might be able to use a connection pooler as kgrittn suggests.  I am not convinced though because it sounds like you need something asynchronous.  I think you will probably need to write one.  This being said I think most of it is doable with components out of the box.  I think you are likely to need some last mile code but that is it.

I would look at building this with three basic components:

1. Message queue.  You could use all kinds of things for this.  You could use email, jabber, RabbitMQ....  Take your pick.  I am guessing that RabbitMQ or the like would be easiest.
2. A small program that would listen on the queue, grab messages, and run the queries on your db.  The database not being available would count as a temporary error.  The program being unable to run them would count as a permanent error.
3. You may want a library to interface and abstract the message queuing (so your app doesn't have to know it is sending stuff to a message queue).